# pdfstrcmp problem with newest miktex

Tags: pdftex, expansion, comparison

I am in need of an string compare function which can be used in various ways.

1. simple compare
2. nested
3. using multicolumn in it
4. as the last line in a tabular, without creating a new line
5. simple compare but with textsubscript in it

All of my use cases were possible with `pdfstrcmp`, but **No.5 stopped** working after a miktex update / reinstall with the error `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line xxx.`

Is this a bug or am I doing something awfully wrong? How would I be able to fix/adjust it?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MY FUNCTION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\STRCMP}[2]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{{#1}}{{#2}}=\z@%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
    \else%
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MY USE CASES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% 1. Simple compare
\STRCMP{a}{b}{1. ERROR}{1. OK} \\

% 2. Nested
\def\b{}
\def\a{\b}
\STRCMP{\a}{}{2. OK}{2. ERROR}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    % 3. Using multicolumn in it
    \STRCMP{a}{}{ERROR \\}{\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3. OK} \\}

    % 4. As the last line of a tabular, without creating a new line.
    \STRCMP{a}{b}{4. ERROR \\}{}
    \hline
\end{tabular}

% 5. Simple compare, but with textsubscript.
% This does not work anymore.
% Error: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 41.
\STRCMP{a\textsubscript{c}}{b}{5. ERROR}{5. OK} \\

\end{document}
```

I already tried the following macros which were not able to account for all use cases.

- ifthenelse (from ifthen)
- IfEq (from xstring)
- \cs_new_eq:NN \strcompare \str_if_eq:nnTF (from expl3)

Using this for checking if the string is null throws the same error because of the `\edef`. But without, it is not able to account for the nested use case.

```latex
\newcommand{\STRCMP}[2]{%
    \edef\TTTTT{#1}
    \if\relax\detokenize{\TTTTT}\relax%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
    \else%
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
    \fi%
}
```

Comment: I think a safer comparison for what you want to do is `\if\expandater\valign\romannumeral\`\^^@#1\valign empty \else not empty\fi`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Works like a charm for the empy/not empty case. Do you have another idea for the string comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2020-10-01 latex released changed `\textsubscript` from

```
\def\@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
```

to

```
\def\@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size#1}}}}}
```

so the subscript text was set with an appropriate line height (this only makes a difference in constriuctions explicitly testing the baselineskip within the superscript to construct raised symbols etc)

in an expansion-only context the old version expanded to nonsense but accidentaly avoided an error so your strcmp was comparing

```
\protect {\mathsurround \z@ \protect $\relax ^{\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \hbo
x {\protect \afterassignment \edef 10.95{10.95}\afterassignment \edef 13.6pt{13
.6pt}\edef {}\let \def \size@update {\baselineskip 13.6pt\relax \baselineskip \
baselineskip \normalbaselineskip \baselineskip \setbox \strutbox \hbox {\vrule 
height.7\baselineskip depth.3\baselineskip width\z@ }\let \size@update \relax }
\protect \xdef \OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 {\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 }\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 \size
@update \enc@update c}}$}
```

But (somewhere) using `\sf@size` instead of `\z@` makes it error in the new code (which is actually a better result in many ways)

You could prevent `\textsubcript` expanding by, for example

```
\let\mytextsubscript\textsubscript
\protected\def\textsubscript{\mytextsubcript}
```

Comment: 1. Could there be any problems from avoiding the expansion?

2. Am I correct, that there is no better way than to protect all functions I use to avoid this problem (textsuperscript, textsubscript, and maybe more I haven't found yet)?

Comment: @Carsten there are always problems in a macro expansion language system like tex, you make a "totally safe" internal change and something somewhere breaks, as you showed.

Comment: Perhaps note that using an `\edef`-like expansion on user text is never supported in LaTeX? Needs to be `\protected@edef` followed by some detokenization?

Comment: Or `\text_expand:n`, which does try to work properly by expansion?

Comment: @JosephWright Using `\protected@edef` fixes the `\textsubscript`-bug, but it is not usable in a tabular environment. Do you think that `\text_expand:n` could handle that, too? I have unfortunatly no idea from expl3 syntax and don't now how I can implement it. Could you give me hand here?

Comment: @Carsten actually \protected definitions also start a table cell so can't be used with empty rows or multicolumn etc